# How to solve the issue with preloader and session storage in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have a problem with the pre-loader. I was trying to set it up as once per session. It works first time, but when you refresh the website the pre-loader does not stop at all and it is impossible to see the content of the website until the moment I will delete the data from the session storage. Adding `visibility: invisible` in to stylesheet does not work at all.

```
canvas {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"><img id="logo" width="1280" height="1024"  alt="logo"></canvas> 
<div> 
  content
</div>
```

```js
if (sessionStorage.getItem('dontLoad') == null){
  jQuery("#c").delay(1000).fadeOut('slow', function(){
    jQuery( "body" ).animate({
      visibility: visible
    }, 1000);
  });
  sessionStorage.setItem('dontLoad', 'true');
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work after the first time because you've set the `dontLoad` flag which prevents the `fadeOut()` from ever being called.

Comment: What should I use instead of dontLoad?

Comment: You need to restructure your HTML and CSS. They way it's setup right now the loader will *always* be displayed in CSS and therefore will always *have* to be hidden in JS

Answer (score 0):

**The problem is that you need to change the CSS. I will try to explain.**

In your CSS, you have set the canvas to `display: none`. In your jQuery, you try to use the `fadeOut` animation. This won't work because the element is not displayed, it is basically removed from the document, so jQuery can't change it.

What you need to do is set the canvas to `display: block`. So that the 'preloader' is visible when the user accesses the website. Then the 'preloader' will fade out.

Here is the updated CSS.

```
canvas {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000000;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

JavaScript

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem('dontLoad') == null)
{
    jQuery("#c").delay(1000).fadeOut('slow', function()
    {
        jQuery( "body" ).animate({
            visibility: visible
        })
    }, 1000);
}

if (sessionStorage.getItem('dontLoad') == true)
{
    $('#c').css('display', 'none');
}
```